# ECLIPSE NEON.2 updates failing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install an update of the STS in Eclipse NEON.2 (on MacOS Sierra) via: Help > Install New Software --> https://dist.springframework.org/snapshot/IDE/nightly.
Then I get: 'Install Software has encountered a problem. An error occurred while installing the items'

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=_Applications_eclipse_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations 2.5.0.v201504151636, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.
Could not acquire the framework manipulator service
```

This issue also arose when trying to install the Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0 plugin for Eclipse.
Then I tried to install any random plugin, and got the same problem.
I imagine this is a permissions issue, but even when I tried to run eclipse using the sudo command, I was still getting the above error when trying to do the installations.
Has anybody come across this issue? Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just a note for anybody who may have come across the same or a similar issue and wasn't sure why it was happening: I have Eclipse installed on a Mac (macOS 10.12.12), in the /Applications folder. I assume this has to do with permissions, but even after I ran Eclipse from the command line in sudo mode, or changed the permissions on the directory, it didn't solve anything. Moving Eclipse to a directory under ~/ bypassed the problem (but still not solved!).